# What's the difference between List<Type/*1*/>> and List<Type/*2*/>>

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I was making a Todo App in flutter but got stuck thanks to an error in in my code:
`Error: The argument type 'List<Todo/*1*/>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Todo/*2*/>'.

- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Todo/*1*/' is from 'package:Database/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
- 'Todo/*2*/' is from 'package:Database/model/Todo.dart' ('lib/model/Todo.dart').
  ? new TodoList(todo: todoList)`

All types are of List but it's telling me that values can't be assigned. I've tried casting but doesn't seem to fix the issue.
So my question is What's the difference between the List types. if I know I can find a fix myself(I'm trying to rely on my nkowledge of things to fix errors. it's a challenge for myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have two different classes with the same name.

Even with the same class name, those classes are different. You can map your first List to the type List by using the map function:

list.map( (todo1) => Todo2() ).toList()

Answer (score 0):

you can import `Todo` class like `import 'package:Database/model/Todo.dart' as model` and have your list like this: `List<model.Todo>`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had two classes with the same name so Flutter was confused which one I'm pointing to.